# Is there any way to make text both bold as well as italic in ppt using apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi

In apache poi there are methods to make text bold or italic or underline, like I did as below,

```
textBox.appendText(text, false).setBold(true);
textBox.appendText(text, false).setItalic(true);
textBox.appendText(text, false).setUnderlined(true);
textBox.appendText(text, false).setStrikethrough(true);
```

But I'm not able to do all the things on the same text like bold and italic and underline:

"***Example***"

So, how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
TextRun run = textBox.appendText(text, false);
run.setBold(true);
run.setItalic(true);
run.setUnderlined(true);
run.setStrikethrough(true);
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephen C for the help, its exactly what I was looking for.